# Need Constructive Criticism of my answer

Tags: discussion

I answered this question today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270171/convert-code-vb-net-to-c-sharp/31270612#31270612 And had my answer accepted relatively fast. Another user posted an answer with a copy paste of some auto-converted code that still had the relevant bugs in it, which he edited out a little while later.

> > Cannot convert method group 'GetRequestStream' to non-delegate type 'Stream'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
>
> This is expecting you to be calling a method. Try:
>
> ```
> Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
> ```
>
> You need the parentheses at the end of it to make it a method.
>
> ```
> cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'
> ```
>
> Calling the Split Method expects you to pass it a char, not a string.
>   Try:
>
> ```
> string[] p = proxy.Split(':');
> ```
>
> the double quotations you had originally was making it a string not a
>   char

Around the same time I received a down vote while his received an upvote, which was strange to me. I edited my post to include a little bit more explanation in case that was the reason, but I guess I am just looking for some constructive criticism to my answer here. Was I too vague? Is there something I could have done better? amd I just being whiney?

Comment: My two cents: you should not have answered that question in the first place. Here it is in a nutshell: *I used an automated tool to convert VB.NET code (which I don't understand) into C# (which I don't understand either). There are errors, please fix them for me.* Such questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow and should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Fair enough. I guess i was confused on what the other guys answer did t warrant an upvote while mine seemingly had issue with it?

Comment: Meh, your answer explains the issues better than the other one (which doesn't explain *anything*). So I would say your answer is "better", yes, my first comment notwithstanding.

Comment: @psoshmo Perhaps the user was expecting an answer that provided a copy-paste solution designed to make the error go away without expecting the reader of the answer to know how to do something as simple as invoke a method.  It's sad, but the reality is some people really do think that that is a better answer than something explaining how to solve a problem.  But I agree with Frederic; when someone doesn't even know how to do something as simple as invoke a method, they're beyond the scope of help a site like SO can provide.

Comment: very possible your DV comes from the other answerer, who wanted his answer to have a better score than yours? but yeah, I'm with Fred here.... this type of question is just bad form in general

Comment: Well....It seems like I summoned the wrath of StackOverflow Meta on the question.....  :P

Comment: @psoshmo yeah... the meta effect can be a harsh mistress :P

Comment: @Patrice Goodbye sweet internet points, I hardly knew thee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn't get an answer yet but lots of good comments, here is a quick wrap up:

- You should probably not have answered the question in the first place, as it is not on topic on the site. I'm not holding it against you that you did, but when you answer questions where the original poster does not actually understand the problem domain very well things get... weird.
- Given that you did answer the question, your answer was good. It was short, concise and explained the issue OP had in a clear manner.
- The other answer was not good, it was a code dump and didn't explain anything.
- The system isn't perfect, sometimes bad content gets upvoted and good content gets downvoted, this is even more common in bad questions, which is another reason to downvote(, close vote) and move on.
- The downvote on your answer could have come from many reasons, we can't know for sure. It might have been strategic voting, or someone didn't like the fact you answered the question in the first place or anything else really. I wouldn't downvote it. As an "answer style" it's fine.

Comment: sounds good. sometimes its hard to not answer low hanging fruit like that though.....these dirty internet points are like crack.

Comment: @psoshmo hehe, although I'd argue answering good questions is a lot more rewarding. A single answer like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593#16825593 is over 3000 reputation over time (and it's on an "old" question that was answered before). Investing in good content pays off.

Comment: Yeah - it's too easy to get sucked into vampire-hell.  You knock out some code as a guide to show them thow to fix their problem, they copy/paste it into their rubbish, find a some simple problem and, instead of just fixing it, (they're clueless and don't know how), they downvote you for supplying buggy code.  Such users are radioactive and should not be approached.  Their questions should have a half-life of one minute before they are downvoted to lead.